# Is enforceFIPSPolicy config key setting is not compatible with web applications/services?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, fips

Is enforceFIPSPolicy config key, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) meant for windows application only?

On my development machine (Windows 7) I enabled FIPS and then If I created a simple console app, as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
    Console.WriteLine("Algorithm created!");
}
```

When I run it I get FIPS error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows 
Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
```

Then if I add following under `configuration` element in `app.config` file:

```
<runtime>
  <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

The application executes successfully.

Now if I do the same thing in the web application (ASP.NET MVC 4):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var alg = new RijndaelManaged();
    return View();
}
```

The code will fail, even if I add same config section in the application web.config file.

I was also able to observe the same behavior in WCF web service.

I would assume that this has to do with the fact that web applications and web services are hosted in IIS (although I reproduced the same behavior with Cassini as well).

Is there any way to have a web app to "opt out" of FIPS checks same way we can do it for windows applications? Has anybody been successful in doing that?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately not, w ended up rewriting FIPS-incompatible pieces

Comment: Thanks, was this a lot of work? We are using md5 and what scares me is if it hashes are saved and with the changes it will not be able to read them.

Comment: We were lucky and were able to tune parameters between FIPS approved and non-approved version of AES so that no data was lost. I do not believe there is FIPS compliant implementation of MD5, see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893088/is-there-an-alternate-hashing-algorithm-to-md5-for-fips-enabled-systems)